# CSS3 Elliptical Gradient in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

I'm trying to get an elliptical gradient in chrome. I've tried

```
    background-image:
    -webkit-gradient(ellipse, center top, 0, center top, 50, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,.5))),
    -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, from(#0A6B9A), to(#29ABE2));
```

No luck. I've tried a few other things I've found on the net and in some books and it all just fails or comes out as circles.

Its easy to do through firefox (cool effect for those interested):

```
    background-image:
    -moz-radial-gradient(40% 0%, circle, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.5)),
    -moz-linear-gradient(50% 100%, #0A6B9A, #29ABE2);
```

Is this possible in chrome? It should be possible according to the planned specs for gradients I've seen. Maybe Chrome just hasn't supported it yet.

**Edit
Oh and I've checked, the style is not being overwritten or any such jazz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-moz` is a CSS property reserved just for Firefox - that's why it doesn't work in Chrome (and in any other browser).

To be more specific, every CSS property started with `-` is not standard and will work just for specific browsers. It's used only for compatibility. If browser doesn't understand what the property means, it just skips it, that's why in CSS files there are multiple properties, and it's the same reason `-moz` and `-webkit` will not work everywhere (not only for you).

For CSS3-compatible browsers it should be tone in W3c convention, like

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
```

(the colours are different, just note `background: radial-gradient(ellipse ...`)

You may use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ or any onther CSS gradient generator for this, just set orientation to radial.

Comment: Sweet, that was a fast response. Yea I know about the moz thing, but thanks for including in case I didn't. All the documentation I could find read that chrome only supported the -webkit-gradient version. Guess that's old info. I'll accept yours when the answer time minimum is up.